# Python: call method of another class, specified as parameter of function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know the simplified example below is embarrassingly ugly ... hence why I have come to SO to share it with the world.

I would like to be able to call a class method from `cls`, specifying the particular method within `callmethod`.

```
class cls(object):
    def __init__(self, var1):
        self.var1 = var1
    def method1(self):
        return self.var1 ** 2
    def method2(self):
        return self.var1 ** 3

def callmethod(method, var1):
    methods = {'method1' : cls(var1).method1(),
               'method2' : cls(var1).method2()
              }
    return methods[method]

callmethod('method1', 2)
Out[56]: 4
```

**Is there a way to go about this without creating a (possibly large and cumbersome) dict that links a string form of each method to the actual thing?**

Comment: I mean just using `getattr` would negate the need for that dictionary, but I don't see how your real example and abstract example are connected at all.

Comment: [operator.methodcaller](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is likely just:

```
def callmethod(method, arg)
    inst = cls(arg)
    return getattr(inst, method)()
```

You can think of `a.b` as a syntax sugar for `getattr(a, "b")`

Comment: or think of `getattr(a, "b")` as a function / dynamic way of doing `a.b` :P